# Не могу сделать вертикальный navar с выпадающим списком в 2 столбца

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Стараюсь сделать, navbar в 2 столбца, к сожалению полчуается только в один, подскажите где у меня здесь ошибка ?

Моя цель чтобы были 2 столбца меню при наведении, к сожалению у меня только один столбец. Как можно это исправить ?

Вот пример как должно все выглядить (скрин)

https://www.titool.kz/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот сайт на который должен быть похож конечный результат

```css
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
/* Custom Stuff */
#cssmenu {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 244px;
}
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
  background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAJCAMAAAA8eE0hAAAAUVBMVEX////MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNzc3l5eXg4ODZ2dnMzMzi4uLS0tLe3t7Q0NDV1dXj4+PW1tbk5OTc3NzPz8/R0dH0Zv5RAAAAC3RSTlMAM2YekAmlPHuEAwArv7wAAAA/SURBVHheY2Dl5mdigABGKV5BNnYok4dHQpKFGcrkEefj5gAzQUBABM7kFYQyRcX4mUBMkEpOLrA2IWGwfgYAn0UDZszv8IwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #dddddd);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
#cssmenu li:hover {
  background: #b7242a;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #666666;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 11px 28px 11px 28px;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
#cssmenu ul li span:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a {
  color: #AE0001;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: url(rectangle-arrow-right.png) no-repeat;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover:after {
  background: url(rectangle-arrow-right.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class="active has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Садовый инструмент Ryobi</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>product test</span></a></li>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>sub pro</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Электроинструмент Ryobi</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Система ONE Plus Батареи & Зарядки</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="active has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Промышленный электроинструмент MILWAUKEE</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>hello</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Дорожная техника Wacker Neuson</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Компрессоры KAESER</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить к второму ul display:flex;

```css
/* Starter CSS for Flyout Menu */
#cssmenu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
/* Custom Stuff */
#cssmenu {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  width: 244px;
}
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:first-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li ul ul li:last-child {
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu li {
  background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAJCAMAAAA8eE0hAAAAUVBMVEX////MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNzc3l5eXg4ODZ2dnMzMzi4uLS0tLe3t7Q0NDV1dXj4+PW1tbk5OTc3NzPz8/R0dH0Zv5RAAAAC3RSTlMAM2YekAmlPHuEAwArv7wAAAA/SURBVHheY2Dl5mdigABGKV5BNnYok4dHQpKFGcrkEefj5gAzQUBABM7kFYQyRcX4mUBMkEpOLrA2IWGwfgYAn0UDZszv8IwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #fff), color-stop(1, #ffffff));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #dddddd);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #fff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
#cssmenu li:hover {
  background: #b7242a;
}
#cssmenu a {
  color: #666666;
  line-height: 160%;
  padding: 11px 28px 11px 28px;
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  width: 450px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
#cssmenu ul li span:hover, #cssmenu ul li:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a {
  color: #AE0001;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li {
  background: #dddddd;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: url(rectangle-arrow-right.png) no-repeat;
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub > ul > .has-sub:after,
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover:after {
  background: url(rectangle-arrow-right.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
   <title>CSS MenuMaker</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class="active has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Садовый инструмент Ryobi</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>product test</span></a></li>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>sub pro</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Электроинструмент Ryobi</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Система ONE Plus Батареи & Зарядки</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
               <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="active has-sub"><a href='#'><span>Промышленный электроинструмент MILWAUKEE</span></a>
  <ul>
   <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>hello</span></a></li>
  </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Дорожная техника Wacker Neuson</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Компрессоры KAESER</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

и ещо раз гляньте на код - для одного класа есть пару стилей